# simple wordpress query of categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been consistently frustrated lately with wordpress and the conflicting methods. Coming back to a wordpress project after months of working with laravel is just such a pain in the toocus. That said can someone explain why this very simple query returns zilch?

```
$args = array(
  'type' => 'product',
  'parent' => 16
);

$cats = get_categories( $args );
```

If I var dump the above I get an empty array, ridiculous!

ref article: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your args are incorrect - there is no supported type "product". The "type" argument supports only "post" and "link", and specifies the type of category to return. This should remain 'post' in 99% of the cases.

Perhaps you're trying to get product categories? In that case, this would be a different taxonomy, and therefore would require additional arguments or a different function. Can you please specify what exactly are you trying to pull from the database?

**EDIT:** use the following to get the child categories of a parent category with ID 16:

```
$cats = get_terms('product_cat', 'parent=16&hide_empty=0')
```

Comment: I wrongly assumed that type referred to the post type and included custom content types. I need to pull the taxonomy from the product content type. I tried get_terms instead but that isn't working either.

Comment: What is the taxonomy you're trying to pull? Are you using WooCommerce?

Comment: Yep, its woocommerce. I just need to pull the sub categories of a parent category in the product post type.

Comment: I've edited my comment to show you an example code - it pulls the sub categories of a parent category - see above.

Comment: I spoke to soon, that var returns an empty array

Comment: Instead of `parent=16`, try using `child_of=16`. Also, make sure that 16 is the right ID. A side note: it is always better to make the IDs dynamic against hardcoding them in the code.

Comment: child of also gets me an empty array, dynamic or not it isn't working as documented

Comment: I am certain that you're doing something wrong. Either the ID is wrong (16), or the taxonomy name (product_cat) is not the right one. Just to be sure, can you open that category in the administration, and copy the URL (the part after /wp-admin/) and paste it here?

Comment: also, if i remove that condition entirely i get the parent cats and the sub cats are NOT in the array

Comment: edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=product_cat&tag_ID=16&post_type=product

Comment: I think i got what your problem is. The get_terms() function does not return categories that don't have any posts assigned to. To change that, try to use the following code instead: `$cats = get_terms('product_cat', 'parent=16&hide_empty=0');`